# Connecting to Athena via R

Tags: r, amazon-athena

I am referring to [this article](https://rud.is/b/2016/12/05/interacting-with-amazon-athena-from-r/) for connecting R to Athena.

When defining the driver, I am getting the following error :

> Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found

I did some research and I arrived at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980767/connecting-to-s3-athena-in-r-via-jdbc). The accepted answer has a comment stating the same problem. However, the solution provided (i.e. restarting R) didn't work.

I have written the following code till now.

```
library("pacman")
pacman::p_load("RJDBC")
pacman::p_load("dplyr")

# Downloading Athena driver to the working directory
URL <- 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.0.0.jar'
fil <- basename(URL)
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)

# Defining driver
drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver", fil, identifier.quote="'")
```

I am using RStudio and I am running it on Windows.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: One of the comments for that blog mentions this error when using Java 7.  What Java version do you have?

Comment: @James I used the following command to get the version of Java being used. `J("java.lang.System","getProperty","java.version")` 
**Output: 1.8.0_20**.

Comment: @James I also updated Java to **1.8.0_121** but still the same error. I have also updated the environment variables.

Answer (score 5):

The `download.file` command writes in character mode by default, not binary. You should specify binary mode:

```
download.file(URL, fil, mode="wb")
```

Comment: file.exists(fil) does pass. Also I tried passing the full path while defining the driver, but still got the same error.

Comment: The driver that gets downloaded is corrupt. I downloaded the driver from [this link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.0.0.jar) and it worked. The weird thing is the link given in the program is the same one.

Comment: Good thinking, that's the key.  It looks like download.file writes in character mode by default, not binary.  The correct download command should be `download.file(URL, fil, mode="wb")` for a binary.

Comment: Confirming that James' solution works for me. You may want to change the answer accordingly.