# Connecting to Athena via R on EC2

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I find somebody asking this question here [Connecting to Athena via R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683348/connecting-to-athena-via-r) But the solution that people claimed to work in that post is not working in my case. I am not sure if it is because the URL has changed as time goes by. As Stackoverflow does not allow me to continue asking under that post, I have to start a new one to ask.

On my EC2, I tried to run the follows

```
install.packages("RJDBC")
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
Sys.getenv()
URL <- 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.0.0.jar'
fil <- basename(URL)
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil, mode="wb")
```

I also tried URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.0.1.jar'
But nothing works. I always get error "cannot open URL 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.0.0.jar': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'" Could someone help me to connect to Athena from R here? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In AWS Athena docs, [Using Athena with the JDBC Driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html), they provide with download links for `AthenaJDBC41-2.0.9.jar` and `AthenaJDBC42-2.0.9.jar`:

- https://athena-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.9/AthenaJDBC41_2.0.9.jar
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.9/AthenaJDBC42_2.0.9.jar